# Merge and split columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know how to merge multiple columns, and split them again.

Input data

```
A B C
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

Merge A, B, C to one column X

```
X
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Process something with X, then split X into A, B, C again. The number of rows for A, B, C is same(2).

```
A B C
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

Is there any simple way for this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with df:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

Next, get all values in one column:

```
df2 = df.unstack().reset_index(drop=True).rename('X').to_frame()

print(df2)

   X
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
```

And, convert back to original shape:

```
df3  = pd.DataFrame(df2.values.reshape(2,-1, order='F'), columns=list('ABC'))
print(df3)

   A  B  C
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

Comment: @PaulH Trying to match OP's expected output, but you are correct, it is not needed.

Comment: @ScottBoston, the output of df3 doesn't seem to be the same as shown here. The data may need to be transposed first.

Comment: @Allen I am not getting that result.

Comment: @ScottBoston oh, I think the issue is with df2. it seems the order of df2 is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Allen  Yes, I see, df2 is not ordered. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ScottBoston It's quite intuitive method and works well. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'B': {0: 3, 1: 4}, 'C': {0: 5, 1: 6}})

df
Out[684]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

**Solution**

Merge df to 1 column:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.flatten('F'),columns=['X'])
Out[686]: 
   X
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
```

Split it back to 3 columns:

```
pd.DataFrame(df2.values.reshape(-1,3,order='F'),columns=['A','B','C'])
Out[701]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

Comment: Fuction flatten also seems to be a good idea for merging multiple columns. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

un unwind in the way you'd like, you need to either `unstack` or `ravel` with `order='F'`

**Option 1**

```
def proc1(df):
    v = df.values
    s = v.ravel('F')
    s = s * 2
    return pd.DataFrame(s.reshape(v.shape, order='F'), df.index, df.columns)

proc1(df)

   A  B   C
0  2  6  10
1  4  8  12
```

**Option 2**

```
def proc2(df):
    return df.unstack().mul(2).unstack(0)


proc2(df)

   A  B   C
0  2  6  10
1  4  8  12
```

Comment: `stack().mul(2).unstack()?`

Comment: @PaulH notice that OP wanted values stacked column-wise... that implies bringing row indices upto columns, hence `unstack` first.  Then process with whatever (i chose `mul(2)`), then `unstack(0)` to un wind the stacking.  I chose a poor example in `mul(2)` to demonstrate that nuance

Comment: ahh, in the case of a single-level column index, `stack` and `unstack` do the same thing (which i find odd)

Comment: @PaulH not exactly, depending on which one you do will dictate both the order of the resultant multiindex levels and the order in which the values were unraveled.

Comment: With my `mul(2)` example... yes.  But if I were to `df.unstack().diff().unstack(0)` versus `df.stack().diff().unstack()`... it would not be moot.

Comment: @piRSquared As you expected, I wanted to try some process with combined columns like mul(2). Thank you very much for your answer and suggesting functions ravel and unstack.